# How to download my own DotA 2 videos?

Tags: dota-2

I want to download a replay video of my game. I searched on Google but found nothing. Is there any way to download DotA 2 game video? I mean my own games and not another player's.

Comment: What do you mean? A video file of the camera following your hero?

Comment: One game i play well, so i want to upload it on YouTube. Ya we can stream and record but i have low network speed so cant stream and i try with obs record but video is not properly record don't know issue. So is there any option for download video?

Answer (score 2):

You just start the replay and record it yourself with a video recording software.

I used to do it with Fraps [(Download Fraps)](http://www.fraps.com/download.php). But the free version of Fraps has some restrictions. Most people these days use OBS [(Download OBS)](https://obsproject.com/de/download).

So after you have setup Fraps or OBS you need to put the "Record" function on a hotkey. Then when you are ingame you press the "Record" hotkey and record the things you want to.

In the end you have your recordings as video files. You can use a video editing software to cut your recordings together and add effects. Just search for a free video editing software. In the free ones you can usually do cutting. If you want better effects you probably need to pay. Adobe Premiere Pro or Sony Vegas are two good options. But there is probably a good free one out there ...

If you don't really want to cut your videos, you need to make a good recording that you want to upload.